# How to manage OAuth in Node-Express / Vue web app?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, oauth, passport.js

I'm a bit confused as to how to manage the OAuth flow in my application. I can make it work, but I'm unsure of the best practices, and would like to find some good articles/tutorials/documentation on that topic.

My app is structured as follows:

- A Vue front-end that makes HTTP requests via axios to a back-end
- A Node.js / Express back-end that uses Passport.js allowing local,    Google and Facebook strategies

Passport is configured like this:

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: '/api/login/google/callback'
        },
        async (accesToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            try {
                let user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
                if (user) {
                    if (
                        user.email != profile.emails[0].value ||
                        user.pic != profile.photos[0].value
                    ) {
                        user.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                        user.pic = profile.photos[0].value;
                        user.save();
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    user = await User.findOne({
                        email: profile.emails[0].value
                    });
                    if (user) done(new UserError('existing-user'));
                    const newUser = await new User({
                        googleId: profile.id,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        name: profile.displayName,
                        pic: profile.photos[0].value
                    }).save();
                    return done(null, newUser);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                return done(e);
            }
        }
    )
);
```

And these are the auth methods in my login component:

```
methods: {
        async login() {
            await authClient.login(this.credentials);
        },
        async googleLogin() {
            window.open('/api/login/google', 'loginPopup', 'menubar=on');
            // window.location.href = '/api/login/google';
        },
        async facebookLogin() {
            window.location.href = '/api/login/facebook';
        },
        async requestResetToken() {
            await userClient.requestResetToken({
                email: this.emailReset
            });
        }
    }
```

My confusion comes from the fact that in order to start the OAuth flow, I need to actually leave my Vue app by linking to /api/login/google, which redirects to the Google OAuth page. Once the OAuth is completed, I'm not redirected to my Vue app but to the Node back-end (via the callback setup in Passport config).

One way to make it work is to open that OAuth flow in a popup window, track through my Vue app the content of that window, and as soon as I get the user object I close the window and login the user in the front-end. But somehow that doesn't seem quite right.

Should I find a way to actually have that callback function redirect to my Vue app and get the Vue app to deal with it? Any good resource online with examples to understand that clearly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have almost the same situation (Angular instead of Vue but that doesn't change anything in this regard.) Great question

Answer (score 3):

:) Hello,

For an one page web app you should use [Authorization Code Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow) and with Passport after an oauth attempt you should have a middleware that will redirect you in case of failure or success : [Passport Documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/oauth/):

[image]

And a good exemple for me was this [Traversy Media - backend app with oAuth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBvmnHTQIPY)

I don't think that passport is the problem, the flow of the token is in your case...

Comment: I can't redirect there because that code is in my Node back-end, which is just an API sending data to a Vue front-end. I think the authorization code flow is exactly what Passport.js does behind the scenes, right?

Comment: yes, i think so, too. And also the redirect, yes is in the backend... As i understand it the backend will send the token back to your VUE frontend after it receives it from the 3rd party oauth(google or facebook). you should save the token in frontend localstorage and send it back... at that should complete the flow...

Comment: @StefanDobre problem with "Sending it back" is that the success callback url starts a new browser tab.